# Firefox not updating last save location for one specific site

Tags: firefox, download

Firefox has this amazing feature where it remembers a last save location per website (unless you specifically turn that off so it only remembers one last save location for all websites). However, after a computer crash the last save location for one specific website does not update when I save from that website. The crash happened while saving an image, so that makes sense. The issue doesn't affect any other website.

How do I fix this issue so that the website continues to update the last save location?

I've tried to clear cookies and site data for the website, which logged me out but didn't fix the issue. And Google is no help because I only find answers to how to turn off the per-site functionality, which I tried and then turned on again, but that didn't help. The computer has been restarted. I don't want to completely erase all data in Firefox.

Comment: 1. If about:config key *browser.open.lastDir* is not blank, try deleting the value. 2. Also search on *DownloadDir* to see if any change to *browser.download.useDownloadDir*, *dom.input.fallbackUploadDir* or *services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.useDownloadDir* helps.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That didn't change anything, which is not surprising. I don't think any change to about:config will do anything since I bet the issue is a corruption in the data that Firefox has saved specifically for that one site.

Comment: Another option is to create a new profile and transfer your data there. Bookmarks, passwords (logins)  and history can be exported and then imported. This is, of course, taking a sledge-hammer to drive a brad, but might be still be the quickest solution.

Comment: What is the pref to toggle the per-website dl location feature?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket That's easily Googlable. Put `about:config` in the address bar and change the `browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite` setting to `true`. If it doesn't exist you can add it. You'll find better explanations by Googling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer:

Delete `content_prefs.sqlite` in `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` and restart Firefox.

---

Old answer:
This answer turned out not to work, because the save location became the same for all sites. It probably broke the file and Firefox ended up using the common save location as a fall-back.

Okay. So I found a super technical solution. One that I believe is too technical for most people as I edited a binary file in a text editor... So I don't really recommend this if you don't know what you're doing.

First, I found my profile by going to `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` and in my profile I found `content_prefs.sqlite`. I opened it in a text editor and searched for the name of the folder that the website was stuck saving to. I saw that the path was 33 characters long and was prefixed by `"`, number 34 in ASCII. I changed the path to a different one with the same length, saved and restarted Firefox.

The save location was successfully changed! But it still didn't update when saving, but rather was simply stuck in the new save location instead. So I replaced `"` with `#`, number 35 in ASCII and replaced the path with one that was 34 characters long, saved and restarted Firefox.

This worked! Now the website properly updates the save location.

This would probably have been significantly harder if the length of the save location path didn't coincide with a legible ASCII character...

Comment: This unlocked the site opening save location at the same place every time, but it seems to have broken the whole savePerSite functionality as every save location seems to be the same for every site.